# How to check if a PDF page contains image in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code snippet and I can't find a straightforward way to check if a PDF page contains an image.

```py
    currentPage = 1
    totalPages = pdfreader.getNumPages()
    text = ''
    page = pdfreader.getPage(currentPage)
    while currentPage < totalPages:
        if page == contaimage(contaimage is pseudocode):
            # extract the text with pytesseract
        text += page.extractText()
        currentPage += 1
    print(text)
    return text
```

containimage is pseudo code of the condition I want to create.

Is there a clean way to check if the current page contains images?

Comment: What do you mean by clean? This is already pretty straight forward.

Comment: containimage is pseudocode my bad